# Django error with User form: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, authentication

i followed the lesson to make a user register using Django, he made this code, like what I have made:

```
class CustomUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter Username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter The Email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter The Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User,
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

when run the server this errors displayed:

```
PS E:\osamaStartup> py manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\deep\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "E:\deep\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 480, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 696, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 689, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "E:\deep\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\osamaStartup\osamaStartup\urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    path('', include('store.urls'))
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "E:\deep\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "E:\deep\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 181, in fields_for_model
    opts = model._meta
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: `E:\osamaStartup\osamaStartup\urls.py ` share this file

Comment: from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('store.urls'))
]

# for images

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue

```
class CustomUserForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter Username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter The Email'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Enter The Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control my-2', 'placeholder': 'Confirm Password'}))

    class Meta:
        model = User,  # Remove this comma because its treating it as a tuple
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```